# Dynamic UI Tabset : tabpanel content not change

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use dynamic tabsetPanel where the number of tabPanel changes depending on the selectInput. The tabset shown as expected but tabPanel content is shown only on active tab. Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage (
  selectInput("tabset", "Choose a Tabset to view:",
    choices = c("Tabset One" = "one",
      "Tabset Two" = "two",
      "Tabset Three" = "three")
  ),

  uiOutput("ui")
)#end of ui

cont <- c("TextOne", "TextTwo", "TextThree")

one <- function() {
  tp1 <- tabPanel("TabsetOne_TabOne", lapply(paste(cont), textOutput))
  ts <- tabsetPanel(type="tabs", tp1)
  return(ts)
}#end of TabsetOne

two <- function() {
  tp1 <- tabPanel("TabsetTwo_TabOne", lapply(paste(cont), textOutput))
  tp2 <- tabPanel("TabsetTwo_TabTwo", lapply(paste(cont), textOutput))
  ts <- tabsetPanel(type="tabs", tp1, tp2)
  return(ts)
}#end of TabsetOne

three <- function() {
  tp1 <- tabPanel("TabsetThree_TabOne", lapply(paste(cont), textOutput))
  tp2 <- tabPanel("TabsetThree_TabTwo", lapply(paste(cont), textOutput))
  tp3 <- tabPanel("TabsetThree_TabThree", lapply(paste(cont), textOutput))
  ts <- tabsetPanel(type="tabs", tp1, tp2, tp3)
  return(ts)
}#end of TabsetOne

server <- function(input, output) {
  ds <- reactive({
    switch(input$tabset,
      "one" = one(),
      "two" = two(),
      "three" = three()
    )#end of switch
  })#end of reactive

  output$ui <- renderUI({
    ds()
  })#end of renderUI

  output$TextOne <- renderText({
    paste("Text Output One")
  })#end of TextOne

  output$TextTwo <- renderText({
    paste("Text Output Two")
  })#end of TextTwo

  output$TextThree <- renderText({
    paste("Text Output Three")
  })#end of TextThree

}#end of server

runApp(list(ui=ui, server=server))
```

Comment: Look into [conditionalPanel](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/conditionalPanel.html)